# how to use nested for loop and pandas's iloc to locate row and column that has 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to python and pandas. I am trying to replicate a battleship game. My goal is to locate the row and column that has 1 and storage that location as the Battleship location. I created a CSV file and it looks like this

```
col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0
```

This is the code to read the created CSV file as a DataFrame.

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.read_csv('/content/pandas_tutorial/My Drive/pandas/myBattleshipmap.csv',)
print(df)
```

How do I use nested for loop and Pandas' iloc to locate the row and column that has 1(which is row 3 and column 1) and storage that location as the Battleship location?

I found out that a nested for loop and pandas iloc to give the entire dataframe look something like this

```
for x in range(len(df)):
  for y in range(len(df)):
    df.iloc[:,:]
```

Do I have to put the if statement to locate the row and column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need to loop, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/content/pandas_tutorial/My Drive/pandas/myBattleshipmap.csv',)
r, c = np.where(df.astype(bool))

print(r.tolist())
print(df.columns[c].tolist())
```

Ouput:

```
[3]
['col1']
```

---

#### For loops like you trying...

```
for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    for y in range(df.shape[1]):
        if df.iloc[x, y] == 1:
            print(f'Row: {x}, Col: {df.columns[y]}')
```

Output:

```
Row: 3, Col: col1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but I need to use the nested for loop and Pandas' iloc as a requirement and I have not started on how to use NumPy yet.

Comment: I just saw your update. Thank you for your help and quick replies! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Use `where` to turn all values that are not 1 to `NaN`, then stack will leave you with a MultiIndex Series, whose index gives you the (row_label, col_label) tuples of everything that was 1.

```
df.where(df.eq(1)).stack().index
#MultiIndex([(3, 'col1')],
#           )
```

---

If you don't want the column names, perhaps get rid of the column labels. IF you only expect a single location we can grab that with `.item()`:

```
df.columns = range(df.shape[1])

print(f'The Battle Ship Location is: {df.where(df.eq(1)).stack().index.item()}')
#The Battle Ship Location is: (3, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But is there any way to change the MultiIndex to Battleship location and 'col1' to 1 instead? I want my end result to look something like this. Battleship location: ( 3 ,  1 )

Comment: @Loon One option would be to remove the column labels in favor of the range index

Comment: thanks for the quick replies and extra option! Appreciated it!